# How can I set the statusline for taglist?

Tags: vim

I set `statusline` for Vim, but that also changes the statusline for taglist windows.

How can I set `statusline` for a specific window like taglist?

Answer (score 1):

`autocmd FileType taglist setlocal statusline=\ taglist`.

But its development has stalled and you might want to have a look at the alternative [tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.io/tagbar).

(Also read up on `:help :setlocal`.)